# Do compilers automatically optimise repeated calls to mathematical functions?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

Say I had this snippet of code:

```
#include <cmath>

// ...

float f = rand();
std::cout << sin(f) << " " << sin(f);
```

As `sin(f)` is a well defined function there is an easy optimisation:

```
float f = rand();
float sin_f = sin(f);
std::cout << sin_f << " " << sin_f;
```

Is this an optimisation that it's reasonable to expect a modern C++ compiler to do by itself? Or is there no way for the compiler to determine that `sin(f)` should always return the same value for an equal value of `f`?

Comment: Unless `sin` is defined in the same compilation unit, the compiler does not know how `sin` is implemented, so at best this would happen at link time.

Comment: @Thomas Not necessarily. Several compilers treat functions of certain names specially because they know they're defined in the standard library, and the standard guarantees something about them. There's also compiler-specific function attributes that user-defined headers can use to declare themselves pure, though I don't know if this knowledge is used for optimization.

Comment: The optimization is indeed done with gcc.

Comment: If I was a compiler writer I certainly would.

Comment: Part of the problem is knowing that `std::ostream::operator<<` didn't change the value of `f`.

Comment: And that `<<` didn't change the rounding mode, or reset the exception flags, etc.

Comment: @aschepler It’s actually not because the order of evaluation here is undefined so the compiler can put the order any way it likes.

Comment: That's true - my motivation behind the question was for a more general passing-by-value situations. Perhaps I should have used `sprintf`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse No. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using g++ built with default optimization flags:

```
float f = rand();
40117e: e8 75 01 00 00          call   4012f8 <_rand>
401183: 89 44 24 1c             mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
401187: db 44 24 1c             fildl  0x1c(%esp)
40118b: d9 5c 24 2c             fstps  0x2c(%esp)
std::cout << sin(f) << " " << sin(f);
40118f: d9 44 24 2c             flds   0x2c(%esp)
401193: dd 1c 24                fstpl  (%esp)
401196: e8 65 01 00 00          call   401300 <_sin>  <----- 1st call
40119b: dd 5c 24 10             fstpl  0x10(%esp)
40119f: d9 44 24 2c             flds   0x2c(%esp)
4011a3: dd 1c 24                fstpl  (%esp)
4011a6: e8 55 01 00 00          call   401300 <_sin>  <----- 2nd call
4011ab: dd 5c 24 04             fstpl  0x4(%esp)
4011af: c7 04 24 e8 60 40 00    movl   $0x4060e8,(%esp)
```

Built with `-O2`:

```
float f = rand();
4011af: e8 24 01 00 00          call   4012d8 <_rand>
4011b4: 89 44 24 1c             mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
4011b8: db 44 24 1c             fildl  0x1c(%esp)
std::cout << sin(f) << " " << sin(f);
4011bc: dd 1c 24                fstpl  (%esp)
4011bf: e8 1c 01 00 00          call   4012e0 <_sin>  <----- 1 call
```

From this we can see that without optimizations the compiler uses 2 calls and just 1 with optimizations, empirically I guess, we can say the compiler does optimize the call.

Answer (score 17):

I'm fairly certain GCC marks `sin` with the non-standard pure attribute, ie `__attribute__ ((pure));`

This has the following effect:

> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables. Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

And so there is a very good chance that such pure calls will be optimized with common subexpression elimination.

(update: actually cmath is using constexpr, which implies the same optimizations)

Comment: Just to add to this, MSC knows about a few such functions and can generate the according code inline.

Comment: `constexpr` does _not_ imply pure.  It's possible to implement a conforming `constexpr` that randomly throws exceptions for certain inputs.

Comment: gcc also optimizes if you only include <math.h> which doesn't have an attribute, it knows about them internally, and marks sin as "const" unless you pass -frounding-math where it is only "pure".

Comment: It's worth noting that __attribute__((pure)) is a gcc extension, not a part of the C or C++ standard.  Other compilers probably have similar extensions, but don't count on it without checking.