# Compiler optimisation double function call

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization

In the following function:

```
long power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
           return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
           return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2);
    return x * power(x, n-1);
}
```

This should of course be written differently, like so:

```
long power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
           return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
           long res = power(x, n/2);
           return res * res;
    }
    return x * power(x, n-1);
}
```

However, will a good compiler like gcc be capable of recognising that the output power function depends on its arguments only, optimising the double function call away?
If not, where is the approximate boundary for a compiler to remove 'double' code?

Comment: You can test if the compiler will optimize it by compiling it and looking at the assembly.

Comment: The tail recursion form may actually be better for optimizations. Compilers are quite good at turning those into simple loops.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/5p7CeW shows that the fcalls are totally optimized out.

Comment: Flagging the function with `__attribute__ ((pure))` may provide a useful hint to the optimizer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509628/do-compilers-automatically-optimise-repeated-calls-to-mathematical-functions?rq=1

Comment: @StoryTeller Neither version is tail recursive.

Comment: @molbdnilo, The first form is far more easily mistaken for one than the other :)

Comment: @GillBates Thanks for looking at the assembly output. As I have no understanding of assembly code, could you tell me where to look and how this 'shows' the (near) equivalence of the two pieces of code I wrote above?

Comment: @StoryTeller You mention that because of the tail recursion, the compiler might be better able to optimise the more trivial piece of code. Would you argue this means that the two pieces of code in my original question are indeed (nearly) equivalent?

Comment: @StoryTeller There seems to be a difference, as the functions from <cmath>, like the 'sin' function to which there is reference, are marked as 'const', while my function is not marked as such.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes I'd argue that. Caching the return value is a very simple optimization to make, even without loop unrolling. The only caveat is that the compiler must know the call has no side-effects, otherwise it won't do it.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Neither of these functions is tail-recursive.

Comment: @EOF - Considering reading previous comments before repeating them. Regardless, what they are is tail recursive modulo cons. And so, can also probably be optimized.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Consider deleting incorrect comments.

Comment: @EOF - I can't say what I want to you, due to SO's regulations. But imagine I did. Discussion over.